# Wire potentiometer to dim LED with only 2 legs

Tags: led, diodes, dc, potentiometer

Can this work to dim the LED?:

[image: Diagram]

And let the third leg free?

Comment: Yes. But add a series resistor so you can't go too low and blow the LED since a pot connected that way can go all the way to zero Ohms. Use a fixed resistor of the minimum the LED can handle.

Comment: How to calculate the Ω needed to drop the voltage from(12V from battery to 1.3V(LED voltage)). I tried using ohms law:
`Ω=V/A`
`Ω=(12-1.3)/A`
`Ω=10.7/A`
I don't know where to find the ampers to complete the division. I tried using the amperage from the battery and that would be:
`Ω=10.7/0.5`
`Ω=21.4`
It doesn't seem a right value for a resistor.

Comment: You need the LED max current from its datasheet. Current through LED = current through resistor. Your 12-1.3 is the voltage across the resistor. By deciding the current in the resistor you get the current in the LED since they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for a while.

A potentiometer such as you have pictured will have a maximum power rating of, typically, 200 mW or so. That means that the maximum current it can handle is given by \$ I = \frac P V \$. Your 10 kΩ pot will have a maximum current rating of 0.02 mA. Your LED will need 1 to 20 mA to light brightly.

> How to calculate the Ω needed to drop the voltage from (12 V from battery to 1.3 V (LED voltage)). I tried using ohms law: Ω = V/A = (12 - 1.3)/A = 10.7/A I don't know where to find the amperes to complete the division.

Use the rated current of the LED or whatever current lower than that you want.

e.g. For 10 mA you get \$ R = V/I = \frac {12 - 1.3} {0.01} = 1070 \ \Omega \$. A 1 kΩ resistor would be fine.

Comment: Thanks! The potentiometer from img is not the one I have, that's the closest I found in the scheme-it free online tool. The potentiometer I have is 0.125W

Answer (score 0):

You can try that (be sure to add the series resistor as suggested by others), however the pot resistance becomes quite important- if it's too high you will not be able to dim to the desired amount with that circuit.

It's possible to add a resistor across the LED to steal away some current and allow it to go a bit dimmer, or buy a higher resistance pot. If the pot is too high resistance then you may see most of the visual brightness change taking place right at the very end of the electrical angle.

Anyway, if you have series resistor properly chosen to prevent the LED and pot from being destroyed and pay attention to the maximum power rating and wiper current specification of the pot you won't likely hurt anything.

BTW, 1.3V sounds a bit low for LED Vf, at least for a visible LED, unless  you are operating it at very low current.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want 20mA for full brightness at a voltage of 2V (say), you need to drop 10V, meaning you want a fixed resistor of 10V/20mA = 500ohm in series with your pot in order to avoid the LED going up in flames.  Now at 20mA, a .125W pot is limited to 6.25V across the whole track (corresponding to a resistance of 312.5ohm).  If we allow somewhat more current for a partial track, that lands us with 500ohms max, probably less.  That means we are not even going to be able to dim the LED to half brightness even with a series resistor.

Independent of that it tends to be good practice to short the wiper to the unused end of the track when using the pot as a rheostat.  Wiper contact is intermittent and having the rest of the track as backup reduces the impact of that.